# How to get partition column name from partition table in oracle server

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

I am newbie in oracle and i want to get partition column name form partition name.
same query working in `MySQL`:

```
SELECT PARTITION_EXPRESSION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ? limit 1
```

this query will give me partition column name, same output I want in oracle

My oracle create table query is look like this

```
CREATE TABLE part_char_date  
(emp_no NUMBER(11)  , birth_date date  , first_name VARCHAR2(100),
last_name VARCHAR2(100)  , gender CHAR(1) , hire_date DATE  ) 
PARTITION BY RANGE  ( hire_date )  
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')), 
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2008', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),   
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-7-2009', 'DD-MM-YYYY')), 
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) )
```

now I want get partition column.
any one help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean the partition key column then

```
SELECT
    OWNER,
    NAME,
    OBJECT_TYPE,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    COLUMN_POSITION
FROM
    ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS
WHERE
    NAME = 'PART_CHAR_DATE';
```